# Como fazer quebra de linha ionic 3

Tags: ionic2, angular, ionic3

Estou tentando quebrar linha dentro de um objeto em ionic 3, já tentei com \n, \n com 
 e nada funciona o texto sempre sai numa única linha, alguém souber uma solução agradeço, segue o código

```
export const listaCafe = [
  ingredientes: 
    "2 copos de farinha de grão-de-bico\n"+
    "2 copos de leite\n"+
    "4 colheres (chá) de fermento químico em pó\n"+
    "3 unidades de ovo\n"+
    "1 colher (chá) de sal\n"+
    "3 colheres (sopa) de manteiga sem sal\n"+
    "• tempero sugestão: salsinha, cebolinha, coentro e alecrim."
 ]
```

no meu arquivo ts eu faço um for e recupero os dados e faço a ligação com uma string interpolation na view

```
 <div>
     <p>{{ingredientes}}
 </div>
```

Comment: Já tentou <br>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução que achei para quebra de linha foi setar no css white-space='pre-line'